# C++ program giving garbage value to an initialized variable

Tags: c++

I'm just starting out with C++ and writing very basic programs to understand the fundamentals. I wrote a simple code to take in a string and integer via user input (Code attached below). When I give input as **35 Tom** (deliberately giving inputs in wrong sequence to see the type sensitivity) I get output **Wow 35!!! I didn't realize that you are 0 years old**, as shown here:

[image]

I can't understand why I am getting a garbage value as I've initilized the integer variable `int age = -1;`. I was expecting **Wow 35!!! I didn't realize that you are -1 years old** as output.

My thinking is that for some big complex programs, there might be a need to get initialized value as the output to help identify the logic-error. I'm just confused as to why I'm not getting the initializeed value as the output?

Attaching the complete code below.

```
// Asking name and age a different way
#include "C:\Dev\cpp\headerFiles\std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your first name and age \n";
    
    string name;
    // Initializing the integer variable. If not done, this will have garbage value by default
    int age = -1;
    
    // Below statements equivalent to: cin >> name >> age;
    cin >> name;
    cin >> age;

    cout << "Wow " << name << "!!! I didn't realize that you are " << age << " years old\n";
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you passing in *Tom 35*?

Comment: I am just trying to see the type senstivity of the input operation. As I'm just starting with C++, hence experimenting and observing.

Comment: **Read a good  [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html)** and the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). with GCC, compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html).... See [this C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm reading the book by Bjarne Stroustrup and I'm getting different results from the book ([link](https://www.amazon.in/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C-ebook/dp/B00KPTEH8C/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=fundamentals+of+c%2B%2B+bjarne&qid=1598168758&s=books&sr=1-1)).

Comment: Consider also using [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang C++ static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your C++ source code (some of which could be generated by tools like [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) or [SWIG](https://swig.org/)...)

Comment: **Your `#include` line is wrong** and makes your code non-portable. See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). You want `#include <ofstream>`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You've shared some excellent resources (undefined behaviour and ASLR looks quite interesting). I'll definitely read them in detail. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it is not working?**
Code in C++ when compiles does not read all the lines at the same time instead, it read the code from line to line. Since you have declared "cin >> name" first, it is asking for the **string** input first (35 can be int or string both), that is why it is getting accepted 35 as valid input. After this, you are taking "cin>>age" in which you are giving input as a string, which it cannot take as age is declared as **int**, hence it is giving "0" like garbage. Although, it is not depending on the fact that you have initialized it or not in this case, but in many cases, it does depend, so it is a good habit to initialize your variables.

**How to fix??**
If you do not want to change the input you are giving(35 Tom) then, change the code to:

```
cin >> age
cin >> name
```

Or simply

```
cin >> age >> name // If you are taking many inputs, it is a good habit
```

Another thing you could do is change the input to:

```
Tom 35
```

**Remember!!** It matters in which order you ask or give your input in C++.

Comment: The 0 isn't garbage. Since C++11 the variable will be set to 0 if the extraction fails. I think [this is correct Standard Reference](http://eel.is/c++draft/facet.num.get.virtuals#3.3.6).

Comment: I am not trying to get the correct answer here. I just wanted to know that why I'm not getting the initialized value as the output. In the comments of another answer, I was told that after C++11 in case like this value 0 (not sure specifically if it's 0 or garbage value) is given as output. I'll accept your answer as it's very well explained.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, Just read the reference you gave, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You've just initialized the `age` at the very beginning, but they're modified as soon as you entered:

```
35 Tom
```

Note that your program accepts the following format: `std::string int` But, since you've given `Tom` string in the place of `Tom`, you get such error.

Two ways to solve this:

1. Change the input format:

   ```
   std::cin >> age;
   std::cin >> name;
   ```
2. Or, change the input:

   ```
   Tom 35
   ```

Your comment:

> *I am just trying to see the type sensitivity of the input operation.*

The `std::cin` will keep waiting for a user input, it won't accept any newline. Note that the initialized value of `age` isn't a garbage, it's signed integer `-1`.

On the other hand, you can verify your inputs using a conditional statement:

```
if (!std::cin.good()) {
    age = -1;    // if the input is given incorrectly, this will take place
    std::cout << "Wow " + name + "!!! I didn't realize that you're " << age
              << " years old.";
}
```

Comment: I'm just experimenting with the type senstivity of the input operation. I was expecting **Wow 35!!! I didn't realize that you are -1 years old** as the output.

Comment: @TusharGautam Yes, you can see the last phase of the answer. Just handle the `!good()` and print the message you want.

Comment: I never said that initialized value is the garbage value. I said that I'm getting garbage value 0 in the output instead of -1. I'm reading the book by Bjarne Stroustrup and getting different results. In the book he said that output should be -1. I'm just confused and don't know if I've made some error.

Comment: @TusharGautam the value was overriden, that's why you got 'zero' because the input was incorrect. Try the last phase of the answer, you'll get your desired results. ;)

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope it clears what I'm going for here.

Comment: @TusharGautam The behavior for a failed stream extraction changed in C++11. Before that the value would be left unmodified. Since C++11 the value is set to 0. It's stated on [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). I don't have a Standard reference..

Comment: @Blastfurnace I just wanted to make sure that I'm not making any errors in my code. Your comment clarifies my concern. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to input in
Tom 35

since you are reading in name, then age.

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope it clears what I'm going for here.

Answer (score 0):

[This is expected behaviour](http://eel.is/c++draft/facet.num.get.virtuals#3.3.6), as someone pointed out already.
It is worth noting that
`cin` goes into a "false state" if the input could not be parsed properly.

https://godbolt.org/z/596jeo

There is no other way than using a temporary variable to check whether the input is correct and THEN setting age to the correct input.
Something like this:

```
int age = -1;
int input;
if(cin >> input){
    age = input;
    cout << "correct" << endl;
    cout << age << endl;
}else {
    cout << "wrong" << endl;
    cout << age << endl;
}
```

this will keep `age` untouched and initialized to `-1` if the input was not correct.